# $_POST Insert into many to many, wrong PHP Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

**EDIT: IGNORE ANY SQL INJECTIONS OR VULNERABLE CODE STATEMENTS :D
(School Project).**

I wish to create a insert form on my webpage where I can select an **artist** from a table, including a **song** from a table and combine them for an insert into a combined foreign key table.

I have managed to do selects and insert with only individual artist and song drop-downs on my web-page, but would **wish for combining the two ID's from each table** to combine them to a many to many relative table. But when I press the submit button nothing happens, and I'm a beginner and don't know if I'm missing any important bits of actually Posting the information.

**For troubleshooting** I have tried my code, and tested it. I see if I remove my code theres no problem, so the problem persists on the syntax I believe, as the first dropdown shows, alongside the second dropdown and submit button, but the problem is within the actual processing and SQL query part, where it never goes to the DB..

**The problem:**
[image]

As you can see below I have a the text Song Name appear with a drop-down menu in the bottom left corner including the Artist Name with a submit button. But my problem persists as the select and then insert from the two **drop downs into the combined table does not work, it does not actually submit, I want it to post into the DB what can I do**.  But somethings off? I would appreciate any questions or help, this community is so amazing and wonderful to operate in!

**Database**
[image: Database in use in code]
**PHP**

```
  <form method='POST'>
<?php

include('connect_mysql.php');
if(isset($_POST["mangetilmange"])) {
  $song_id = $_POST["song_id"];
  $artist_id = $_POST["artist_id"];


$sql ="INSERT INTO artist_has_song (song_id, artist_id) VALUES 
('$song_id', '$artist_id')";

if($conn->query($sql)) {
    echo "Completed";

} else {
    echo "Blablalbablablablablablablabl $sql
    ($conn->error.";
}
}
?>
```

Song Name

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM song";
$resultat = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<select name='song_id'>";

while ($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
$song_id = $rad["song_id"];
$songname = $rad["songname"];

echo "<option value='$song_id'>$songname</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
?>
```

Artist Name

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artist";
$resultat = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<select name='artist_id'>";

while ($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
  $artist_id = $rad["artist_id"];
  $artistname = $rad["artistname"];

echo "<option value='$artist_id'>$artistname</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
?>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="mangetilmange" value ="Submit">
```

Comment: sql injection alert! use parameter binding!

Comment: @delboy1978uk It's a school project, and I'm fairly new, so I haven't gone through the part of protecting my code :D Thanks for the reminder though!

Comment: School projects that litter the internet with yet more examples of code patterns that are well known to be vulnerable to SQL Injection ...  that's not a school I would want to be affiliated with.

Comment: You spent more time telling us to not worry about your SQL injection bugs than it would've taken to fix them. **There are no excuses** for this. [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is one line of code and will save you *hours and hours* of pointless debugging later when someone breaks your app because of a single apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change you code to this:

```
 <form method='POST'>
 <?php

 include('connect_mysql.php');
 if(isset($_POST["mangetilmange"])) {
 $song_id = $_POST["song_id"];
 $artist_id = $_POST["artist_id"];


 $sql ="INSERT INTO artist_has_song (song_id, artist_id) VALUES 
 ('$song_id', '$artist_id')";

 if($conn->query($sql)) {
 echo "Completed";

 } else {
 echo "Blablalbablablablablablablabl"; 
 }
 }
 ?>

 Song Name
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM song";
 $resultat = $conn->query($sql);

 echo "<select name='song_id'>";

 while ($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
 $song_id = $rad["song_id"];
 $songname = $rad["songname"];

 echo "<option value='$song_id'>$songname</option>";
 }

 echo "</select>";
 ?>

 Artist Name

 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM artist";
 $resultat = $conn->query($sql);

 echo "<select name='artist_id'>";

 while ($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
 $artist_id = $rad["artist_id"];
 $artistname = $rad["artistname"];

 echo "<option value='$artist_id'>$artistname</option>";
 }

 echo "</select>";
 ?>
 <input type="submit" name="mangetilmange" value ="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you incredibly much Sam! That worked out perfectly :)!

Comment: Welcome Mads, your problem was at the last line and a few other syntax errors